# SelectedRow Error DataGridView Error

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to get the value from the column when the row is selected. So I tried this code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
}
```

But at the `SelectedRow` it showing this error :

> "Are you missing any directive or assembly reference"

I'm using the two namespaces

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
```

Comment: Are you sure that SelectedRow exist? You forget the 's' at the end. It must be SelectedRows. You must use dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0]. Notice the s at the end of SelectedRows

Comment: Ms Yvette Before posting this question I  searched on Internet and their it is SelectedRow only!

Comment: Hemal I used your code now it's showing same Error at the " .Text" :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems, you are working with windows forms platform, you need to use  `System.Windows.Forms` namespace which can be found in  `System.Windows.Forms.dll` assembly :

Importing namespace will be like this :

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Your code itself need to make correction. If you want to use SelectedRows, then your code should be:

```
dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value
```

And you need to change cell value to string to set in textbox Text property by doing :

```
textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: olCoder 아카 쉬 I already using the System.Windows.Forms namespace but error was not gone :(

Comment: You need to use SelectedRows and get value from selected cell cells like this : dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value

Comment: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Comment: I am getting this exception :(

Comment: It means you don't have any SelectedRows. Please check before using that

Comment: Here is what I am trying to do  adapterFill(ds);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

Comment: I first search by this code which is working perfectly then if i select any row it show the column value so i tried this 
                if (dataGridView1.RowCount > 0)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                }  This if condition only allow if their are rows But still it showing exception:(

Comment: RowCount gives total rows in datagridview so you are checking in wrong way. You need to check this condition :  if(dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0) { textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString(); }

Comment: I tried this now it's not giving exception but it's not working.When I am selecting the row that row individual column value does not showing in the textbox. By this code Textbox showing nothing I does not understand what is problem:(

Comment: I can not assume, what's wrong with your code but you can give try with making "SelectionMode" property to FullRowSelect.

Comment: Now it's working but the problem is it only showing 0th(1st) row and 0th(1column) value when I selected second row still the 1st row,1st column value is showing....:(

Comment: You need to change index of selected rows accordingly. You can  find numerous article on working with selected rows of datagridview.

Comment: Yes I tried to change the Row Index but again throwing exception   
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index :( Yes I will search for articles:) Thanks For giving this much interest in my question:)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this.

```
textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Text;

OR

textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value;
```

Comment: Hemal I used your code now it's showing same Error at the " .Text" :(

Comment: Second one or first one?

Comment: Hmmm, Use `Value` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I understood what you want.Try this code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
            {
               int i = e.RowIndex;
                DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[i];
                textBox1.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                textBox2.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();    
            }
```

From this code when you double click on the any row cells you get that row column values.Hope this solve your problem:)

Comment: Yes Rock it's working even I want when row selected then get the value but when cells double clicked getting value it also acceptable:)

Comment: Ms Yvette,Hemal, LolCoder 아카 쉬,Rock thank you all for giving this much interest to my question:)